# Word for an entity with a vast amount of knowledge?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there some word for a being / entity / intelligence that is either all-knowing or has an amount of knowledge that far exceeds that of a human being?

Comment: All questions here have a research requirement: please show us what words you have already considered but discarded and why. Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered. For help writing a good word or phrase request, see: [About single word requests](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info). Please also read [Single word requests, crosswords, and the fight against mediocrity](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2160/2085) on ELU’s Meta site.

Comment: It is really annoying to spend 20 minutes composing an answer, then find that some heavy handed moderators have closed the question.  Anyhow, here is my answer, without explanation: macheÏde.

Comment: @GregLee Yes, I don't understand why moderators should bee so fast at closing questions (or close them at all), or disqualifying people's answers for various reasons. That prevents both the OP from receiving answers, and the people giving the answers from, well, contributing with their knowledge. Right, tchrist?

Comment: @GregLee: "[Son of Battle](https://heinonline.org/HOL/LandingPage?handle=hein.journals/llj54&div=12)," is that what macheÏde means?

Comment: No.  Apparently a Greek word with that meaning is the etymology,  But it means what Emanuel Lasker coined it to mean.

Comment: @GregLee Okay. So what was that?

Comment: Look at this from Edward Lasker: https://books.google.com/books?id=mibtmchSiv4C&pg=PT352&lpg=PT352&dq=mache%C3%8Fde&source=bl&ots=rXq8FO9yPj&sig=Kk-9VBGVfVZO3cJhn02kzBjLkVE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjkmu_E5-HfAhUni1QKHXozDfgQ6AEwAnoECAIQAQ#v=onepage&q=mache%C3%8Fde&f=false

Answer (score 4):

Such an entity is said to be *omniscient*:

> 1 : having infinite awareness, understanding, and insight
>   // an *omniscient* author
>   // the narrator seems an *omniscient* person who tells us about the characters and their relations— Ira Konigsberg
>
> 2 : possessed of universal or complete knowledge
>   // the *omniscient* God

<sub>(source: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/omniscient))</sub>

It's never used in a literal sense when applied to real humans (the examples for definition 1 come from writing). If I'd call your uncle omniscient, I'd mean that figuratively; he might know a lot, but not so much that his knowledge far exceeds that of other humans.

Comment: If you don't mind, may I ask that you please meditate upon [this guidance from Jon Ericson](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11731/2085) and then consider expanding this into a proper answer? Jon’s post explains why we prefer answers with actual context and explanations, not mere copying of someone else’s words from some googled reference work without including any new content in your own words. Otherwise we aren’t building up a library of expert answers by creating new content; we’re only showing off our own google-fu and adding nothing to our growing expert library..

Comment: Yeah, it's easy to provide a word that for 95% sure fits the OP's intentions, but without more context in the question it's hard to provide *proper* context in the answer. Does that mean we should be harsher in closing questions like this? [Relevant diagram about the current situation on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252077/4751173) - this answer might qualify for group 3.

Comment: Yes, I believe that we should indeed be much harsher in closing questions like this. [So does Shog](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2160/2085).

Comment: Heh, so it's a seven-year-old problem ...

Comment: It’s even worse than that, more like a seven-year-old-on-a-sugar-addiction-high problem. :)

Comment: I respect Shog69 and Jon Ericson, but I wouldn't call them authorities on EL&U and their contributions are spartan,  respectively [one answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/6437/shog9?tab=topactivity) and [two questions and four answers](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/10754/jon-ericson?tab=topactivity) in nearly 8 years, practically non-existent.

Comment: If you're really interested in the debate about SWR, take a look at the list of links which I posted on meta https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11359/three-swrs-suddenly-closed-for-being-pob